# Does WordNet have Levels?

Tags: nlp, wordnet, lemmatization

I'm reading a paper that says to use WordNet level 3 because if he used level 5 would be lost a lot, but I can't see how to use these supposed levels. I don't have his codes, so I can't share them, but I can share the paper. Can you guys help me figure out if it's possible and how to do it? [enter link description here](https://www.michaelwebb.co/webb_ai.pdf) page 16

"In choosing the conceptual level at which to group the nouns, I face a trade-off between specificity and coverage. For example, if I group into categories at the conceptual level of “dog”, I lose all words that exist only at a more general level, such as “mammal” and “animal”. Figure A3 in the appendix displays the share of verb-noun pairs extracted from O*NET tasks that would be lost for this reason at each level of aggregation. Due to the level of generality at which O*NET tasks are expressed, I would lose more than a quarter of all verb-noun pairs if I grouped at WordNet level 5, for example. (Levels with higher numbers are more specific.) I therefore use WordNet level 3 for my main results, and re-run my analyses at levels 2, 4, and 5 to check their sensitivity. While the level of aggregation does make some difference, the results for these other levels are qualitatively very similar to my baseline specification."

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood the paper is that the author chooses a fixed 'depth' level (or distance to 'entity' and groups together all more specific concepts. 'dog' would be at level 8 then.

In wordnet, you can find the word and the 'root' word 'entity' like this:

```
wordnet.synset('dog.n.01').min_depth()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like "level" is within the WordNet hierarchy.

> the ancestors of “dog” include “carnivore”, “mammal”, “vertebrate”, “animal”, and “physical entity”.

"physical entity" is a top-level concept in WordNet; I think the author is putting dog at level 5 so must be counting this as level 0. (Though "entity" is the parent of "physical entity".)

So, there is no explicit "level number" in WordNet entries, but you could get its level in the hierarchy by going up and counting how many hypernyms between it and the top of the tree.

See also [Does WordNet have "levels"? (NLP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1695971/841830)

Comment: thank you for your answer @DarrenCook. So would be something like this :
' from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')
hyp = lambda s:s.hypernyms()
from pprint import pprint
pprint(dog.tree(hyp))'